# How to add default json to Rails standard resource route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

here is my route

```
resources :content_elements, only: [:destroy, :edit, :update], controller: 'contents/content_elements' do
   put :reposition, :on => :member, :defaults => { format: 'json' }
   get :list_images, on: :member
   post :send_image, :on => :member
end
```

I want to add json as default route only for destroy.

I try with

```
  :destroy, :on => :member, :defaults => { format: 'json' }
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Is not the same. Adding defaults: {format: :json} also edit and update respond to json. I need only destroy. And If I use respond_to in controller I need also the html view

Comment: delete :destroy, on: :member, constraints: { format: 'json' }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Doc: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/routing.html

```
resources :content_elements, only: [] do 
   delete :destroy, on: :member, constraints: { format: :json }
end
```

> There is an exception for the format constraint: while it's a method
>   on the Request object, it's also an implicit optional parameter on
>   every path. Segment constraints take precedence and the format
>   constraint is only applied as such when enforced through a hash.

For example,

> get 'foo', constraints: { format: 'json' } will match GET  /foo
>   because the format is optional by default. However, you can use a
>   lambda like in get 'foo', constraints: lambda { |req| req.format ==
>   :json } and the route will only match explicit JSON requests.